# shortcode to display number of products sold by coupon code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, coupon

I have coupon "coupon-test"

I have this snippets to show the number of usage for the coupons

```html
function simple_function_1() {
    
    $coupon_code = 'coupon-test';
    global $woocommerce;
    $coupon_data = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
    echo ($coupon_data->usage_count);// return number of remaining coupons
}
add_shortcode( 'own_shortcode1', 'simple_function_1' );
```

I want to make shortcode to display number of usage for coupon and number of products sold by coupon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output from shortcode functions is presented to WordPress's page construction code by doing `return $theResult;`, not via `echo $theResult;`. Your code uses `echo`, though.